# Rich text field replaces HTML code with actual character

Tags: 2011, rtf

I have a component with a rich text field. In the Source tab I type `&divide;` then switch to the Design tab and the character displays correctly. I then switch to the Source tab and the `&divide;` statement has been replaced by the actual character.

What can i do to stop this happening?

Comment: Don't type `&divide;` in the source tab? But seriously: can you explain what your problem is? Why do you want this not to happen?

Comment: @DominicCronin I was asking on behalf of someone else. Now I think about it you're right, I don't really know why I wouldn't want this to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is valid behaviour and I suspect that you could not restrict it out-of-the-box unless you write a Filtering XSLT to handle your specific special scenario.

The obilus (or divison sign or the ÷ symbol) is a part of ISO-8859-1 character set which is default character set on any browser and you can directly use these symbols in your HTML code in addition to using their character set.

You will get this expected behaviour (as the one defined for divison sign in your question) for other character of this character set as well like - `&copy; &yen; &pound;` etc.

You can get the complete list of these character set [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)